# SQL SERVER 2014 Allocation block size snapshot drive

Tags: sql, admin, sql-server-2014

I am creating a distribution server with separate drives.  One of the drives is going to be for the SNAPSHOT folder.  All my other SQL DATA Drives have 64k block Allocation sizes.

Should the SNAPSHOT drive also have 64K  block Allocation size?  I am thinking it does not matter for the SNAPSHOT, but this will be the first time that I am building a distribution server and I could not find a recommendation for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured replication many times and never bothered about ,changing block size of drive,snapshot is stored..

I also don't see any mention in best practice's section for snapshot mentioning block size,so i would recommend go with defaults